# @font-face: MyriadPro-Cond

Tags: css3, шрифты, css

Как всегда в Опере не работает подключение. Дело в том, что если на Windows 7, то отображает во всех браузерах адекватно, вероятно потому-что, в 7-ке шрифт идет в пакете. Что касается XP, то есть проблемы (периодически не только с оперой). Как вариант, плохой .ttf файл. Но перепробовал их много, и при открытии файла нормально работает. Что тогда может быть?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyriadProCondensed";
    src: url("fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.eot");
    src: local("MyriadPro-Cond");
         url("fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.ttf") format("truetype"); }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
font-family: 'MyriadProCondensed';
    src: url('fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.eot');
    src: url('fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/MyriadPro-Cond.svg#MyriadProCondensed') format('svg');
```

Для кросбраузерного решения должны присутствовать все эти форматы